# How can I insert the current date/time into a datetime data type field using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to insert a row of data into my Application table.

Here's the class:

```
public partial class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        this.TestAccounts = new List<TestAccount>();
    }

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the C# code:

```
_Uow.Applications.Add(new Application { Name = name });
```

It's giving me an error saying

```
  InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
        HResult=-2146233087
        Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
        Source=System.Data.Entity

        InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
             HResult=-2146232060
             Message=The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
             resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

How can I change my C# code to insert the current date in the ModifiedDate field?

Answer (score 0):

Simply that way:

```
_Uow.Applications.Add(new Application
                       {
                           Name = name,
                           ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                       });
```

Or you may do it in the constructor:

```
public class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

By the way: You got the exception because per default c# `DateTime` is more precise than `datetime` of SQL. Like the message says: Use `datetime2` in SQL. `DateTime` has it's min value as initial value, which is too low for SQL `datetime`.

Comment: I recommend keeping field or property initializations like this, that are not influenced by outside factors, in the constructor. In this case, the second example.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a new constructor

```
public Application(string Name)
{
  if(ModifiedDate == null)
   //ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(01.01.2000);
     ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

OR

```
public Application(string Name, System.Nullable<DateTime> modifiedDate)
{
   if(modifiedDate != null)
     //ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(01.01.2000);
     ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
   else
   Do stuff
}
```

This isn't beatifull, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

hi your `ModifiedDate` is initialized with minvalue as a result it gives an exception. Better to use either

```
public System.DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; } to make it nullable or
```

initialize in the construction

```
public Application()
    {
        this.TestAccounts = new List<TestAccount>();
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    }
```

Comment: Not true. `DateTime` is no nullable type per default.

Comment: I just wanted to give him a clue that when the Application type object is initiated, its Modified property is null by default.

Comment: As I said: It cannot be, because `DateTime` is not nullable. It's initial value is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: yes you are right.. its the minvlaue. which cannot be feed in sqlserver datetime.. thank you